# Как узнать имя файла, данные которого мы изменяем?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я прослушиваю события через `watch`.
Как узнать имя файла, данные которого  мы изменили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то, изменяемый файл передается вторым аргументом в `listener`.

Выдержка из документации:

[`fs.watch(filename[, options][, listener])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)

```
fs.watch('somedir', function (event, filename) {
  console.log('event is: ' + event);
  if (filename) {
    console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});
```